# Showing that the order of $xyx^{-1}$ equals the order of $y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I have just started  out learning about groups and I am stuck on trying to solve the following question for a couple of hours now:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $x, y$ be in $G$. Show that order of $xyx^{-1}$ equals order of $y$.

The following is how far I was able to go:

To show that the order of $xyx^{-1}$ equals the order of $y$, I believe all I have to do is show the following:

> Show that $(xyx^{-1})^m=y^n$.

$$\underbrace{(xyx^{-1})(xyx^{-1})(xyx^{-1})\cdots(xyx^{-1})}_{m\text{ times}} = (xy^mx^{-1}).$$

Now I have to show that $(xy^mx^{-1}) = y^n$, but I cannot do $xx^{-1}y^m=y^n$ because I don't know if the group is abelian or not.

Before you ask, this is not a homework question.

Thanks!

Comment: The $m$ and $n$ in your question make no sense. What you have to show is that if $y*n = e$ then so does $(xyx^{-1})^n$, and vice versa. You don't need commutativity for that. What happens if you work out $(xyx^{-1}) $ times itself?

Answer (score 6):

So, if I understad correctly, you have shown that $(xyx^{-1})^m=xy^mx^{-1}$. Now, you have almost finished. You have two options:

If $m$ is the order of $y$, then $y^m=1$, and $(xyx^{-1})^m=xy^mx^{-1}=x1x^{-1}=1$, so the order of $xyx^{-1}$ is, at most, the order of $y$.

If $m$ is less than the order of $y$, then $y^m\neq 1$, and then $xy^mx^{-1}\neq 1$, since that would mean either $(1)$ $xy^{m}=x\Leftrightarrow y^m=1$, which you know it is not, or $(2)$ $y^mx^{-1}=x^{-1}\Leftrightarrow y^m=1$, which, again, isn't. Therefore, the order of $xyx^{-1}$ is no less than the order of $y$.

From here, if you know that $ord(xyx^{-1})\leq ord(y)$ and $ord(xyx^{-1})\geq ord(y)$, it must be that $ord(xyx^{-1})=ord(y)$.

Answer (score 5):

It would be enough to show that $(xyx^{-1})^n = e$ iff $y^n = e$. This follows from noticing that $(xyx^{-1})^n = x y^n x^{-1}$.

Indeed if $y^n = e$ then $x y^n x^{-1}= x x^{-1} = e$. Conversely if $(xyx^{-1})^n = e$ then $x y^n x^{-1} = e$ so multiplying on the right by $x$ and on the left by $x^{-1}$ gives $y^n = x^{-1}x = e$ and we are done.

Answer (score 3):

Note that conjugation by an element is a group automorphism of $G$. Now note that group automorphisms (and more generally isomorphisms!) preserve the order.

Comment: "I have just started out learning about groups ".  Doubt the asker has any clue right now what a group automorphism means, nor the rest of what you state.  Don't get me wrong, you're answer is correct, but not appropriate given the demonstrated cluelessness of this asker.

Comment: @amWhy Depends heavily on the structure of the book OP is reading, but remember answers eventually help other people apart from the OP. :)

Comment: I do remember that answers may help future users, and so I did not downvote your answer.  Ideally, an answer aims to both help the asker, and all those down the road with the same question.  Your answer hypothetically satisfies one of those conjuncts.  In any case, I simply commented with feedback, for you to take or reject. That's your choice, what you want to do with it.  :)

Comment: Just to be clear, I think your concern is legitimate. I just hope the OP can eventually come back to this and understand it.

Comment: Indeed, @Pedro ! +1